# Creating Dynamic controls using MVC JQUERY suggestion

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a following code in my **View**

```
<tr id="tblNewContentRow">
       <td>
     @Html.TextBox("txtNewAttributes", "", new { @class = "alphaonly", style = "width: 155px;" })
       </td>
        <td>
      @{@Html.DropDownList("ddlNewValues", Model.OperandsMaxList, new { style = "height: 20px;" })
        }
       </td>
       <td colspan="2">
       @Html.TextBox("txtNewValues", "", new { @class = "numbersonly", style = "width: 250px;" })
    </td>
 </tr>
```

And i have **ADD** Button for the user  where in they can dynamically add as much TR(Shown Above) they want in runtime.

Currently am using the below code for dynamically generating **TR** using JQUERY

```
var txtNewAttributes = '<td><input type="text" name="txtNewAttributes' + (tblRows + 1) + '"  class="alphaonly" style = "width: 155px;" id="txtNewAttributes' + (tblRows + 1) + '" value="" /></td>';
    var ddlNewValues = '<td><select id="ddlNewValues' + (tblRows + 1) + '" style = "height: 20px;width:75px;" /></td>';
  var txtNewValues = '<td><input type="text" name="txtNewValues' + (tblRows + 1) + '" style = "width: 250px;" id="txtNewValues' + (tblRows + 1) + '" value="" /></td>';
  var repeatRow = txtNewAttributes + ddlNewValues + txtNewValues;
   $('#tblNewSearchAttribute tr:last').prev().after('<tr id="tblNewContentRow' + (tblRows + 1) + '">' + repeatRow + '</tr>');
```

But i have lot of functionality to be done on these dynamic rows after it is rendered.Currently itz bit confusing with this way to make use of the dataEntered.

My Question is

1. Is there a better way i can Handle this so i can easily make use of these datas for all the Functionalities ?
2. What will be the best way of implementing the above scenario ?

Please share your suggestions.

Am pretty new to MVC as well as Jquery.

Thanks

Comment: You can use jQuery.Clone() to create rows dynamically.

Comment: If i create multiple rows how easy ll it be for me to Traverse again ?What ll be the ID for newly generated Rows(TextBox etc ) ???

Comment: What do you mean: "to make use of the dataEntered"? How you implement it so far?

Comment: I mean "To traverse the value user entered in the textbox" is little complicated by this way. want to know if there are anyother easy way of creating dynamic controls and easily captured later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little improvement to your code to make the data retrieval easier:

- Use class instead of id, e.g. class='txtAttributes'
- Should use css for styling, avoid as much as possible styling code.

Your addNewRow function should look like:

```
function addNewRow(){
   var txtNewAttributes = "<td><input type='text' class='txtNewAttributes' /></td>";
   var ddlNewValues = "<td><select class='ddlNewValues'></select></td>";
   var txtNewValues = "<td><input type='text' class='txtNewValues' /></td>";
   var repeatRow = txtNewAttributes + ddlNewValues + txtNewValues;

   $('#tblNewSearchAttribute tr:last').prev().after('<tr class="tblNewContentRow">' + repeatRow + '</tr>');   
}
```

Then the data retrieval function:

```
function retrieveData(){
    var items = [];

    // loop for each row
    $("#tblNewSearchAttribute .tblNewContentRow").each(function(){
        var item = {
            txtNewAtribute: $(this).find(".txtNewAttributes").val(),
            ddlNewValues: $(this).find(".ddlNewValues").val(),
            txtNewValues: $(this).find(".txtNewValues").val()
        };
        items.push(item);
    });

    //  return the array of item, each item contains data for a table row
    return items;
}
```

In case you need to handle some events e.g. handling change event of all txtNewValues in the table, you will see using class instead of id is better:

```
$("'#tblNewSearchAttribute").on("change", ".txtNewValues", function(){
     // do something
});
```

About css:

```
#tblNewSearchAttribute .txtNewAttributes {
    width: 155px;
}

#tblNewSearchAttribute .ddlNewValues{
    height: 20px;
    width:75px;
}
```

Comment: if i have some 10 rows added dynamically "<td><input type='text' class='txtNewValues' /></td>";  how ll i distinguish by itz name during retrieval ?

Comment: but why you need distinguish rows? Thought they are the same. Try to use my retrieveData and see more about jquery each here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Will it fetch Row by row ? Bcoz i need to map Textbox ddl textbox in a row ..form a Array of all rows and send back to server

Comment: retrieveData return an array and you just send it back to server

Comment: Thanks i ll try. i have added +1. If it works i ll  accept answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time :)

Comment: let me know if there is any problems. glad to help :)

Comment: namkha87: Thanks.Tat worked like a charm. am saving these search values in DB (eg: 3 rows) and if user comes back and to see the search values again how ll i reproduce easily ?

Comment: Once user chooses answer will add Bounty 50

Comment: @user2067567: in this case, just loop for the data you read from database and render the corresponding html(using the same structure in addNewRow function) directly in your cshtml file.